# Another Junk Folder is missing issue

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm running Outlook 2010 on my Windows 8.1 laptop (both 64-bit versions). I have one POP, two IMAP and one Windows Live accounts set up.

The POP, Windows Live and one of the IMAP accounts have working Junk, Send, and Trash folders. However, the one IMAP does not have a Junk folder, just the Sent and Trash (they both work).

I've noticed that emails I've marked as "junk" in this particular IMAP account are being copied to my Windows Live Junk email folder. However, the emails are not moved from their location in the particular IMAP folder, nor are future junk emails from the same sender being blocked.

Have tried the "Outlook/ResetFolders" option, but still no Junk folder.

Have also tried setting the Root Folder Path to "Inbox" in the account's Internet Email Settings. This creates a subset of folders under Inbox with Junk, Sent and Trash folders, disabling the pre-existing Sent and Trash folders. However, selecting an email and trying to make it junk or trying to delete has no effect. Also, under this setting, sent emails do not go the Sent folder either. Essentially "Junk", "Sent" and "Trash" functions do not work with the Root Folder set to "Inbox".

Have also tried creating a new user profile, but still same problem.

Thanks for any help!

Don